# set a proper Width for HTML Buttons

Tags: html

When i am using HTML To create a form the buttons are on different sizes (as size of inputted values).

It is possible to set a proper width for `HTML` Buttons With Out using `CSS`.

```
<form>
<input type="button" value="input"><br>
<input type="button" value="ok">
</form>
```

Comment: Hi, can you please show us what you have done? also without css? why is that?

Comment: <form>
<input type="button" value="input"><br>
<input type="button" value="ok">
</form>

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Without CSS? http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_input.asp No, the width attribute of the input element only works when type=image according to W3Schools.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Option1**

See example http://jsfiddle.net/mScnX/

HTML:

```
    <form>
<input type="button" value="input" id='button1'><br>
<input type="button" value="ok" id ='button2'>
</form>
```

CSS:

```
     #button1 {
        width:400px;
     }

    #button2{
        width:100px;
    }
```

**Option 2:**

See example: http://jsfiddle.net/mScnX/2/

HTML:

```
<form>
<input type="button" value="input" style="width:400px"><br>
<input type="button" value="ok" style="width:100px"'>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a couple options.

1) You can use inline styles (not best practice)

```
<button style="width: 50px; height: 20px;">Click Me</button>
```

OR

2) You can use this in a style tag in the head of your page or in an external style sheet.

```
 button {
    width: 50px;
    height: 20px;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no other way to style the html elements. But there is a way to style each button with   tag in your html. Just add

```
   <style>
    input[type="button"] {
        width: 13px;
    }
</style>
```

It's a alternative but is not a good practice at all.